# bash script for take same lines from 2 different file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, sh

I've for example file called users and it's include

```
user1
user2
user3
```

and file called newusers including:

```
newuser1
newuser2
newuser3
```

and now I need bash script for take user1 and newuser1 and do some command for example 'mv user1 to newuser1' and etc.
something like this but this is not working for me:

```
user=cat users
newuser= cat newusers

for u in user ; for n in newuser; do mv $u $n done; done
```

Comment: `user=cat users` runs a program names _users_ and sets the environment variable `user` to the string _cat_. Plese focus on one problem at one time (for instance _how do I assign a value to a variable?_). Also, make it clear whether you want to organize your user names in an array or in a scalar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you nest the two loops, you get "number of users" * "number of newusers" move operations. But you want only "number of users" move operations.

Pure Bash:

```
#! /bin/bash

exec {users}<users
exec {newusers}<newusers

while true; do
  read user <&$users || exit
  read newuser <&$newusers || exit
  mv "$user" "$newuser"
done
```

Comment: It works, than you a lot. You save my time.Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the files are in matching order, and the same number of lines:

```
tab=$(printf '\t')

paste users newusers |
while IFS=$tab read user newuser; do
    echo "move $newuser $user"
done
```

It works in bash or `sh`. You can build a command using the corresponding lines. The lines can't already contain tabs.